# DefaultTableModel addRow method adds row in format: column_name = column_value instead of just column_value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am experiencing a issue while trying to add new row in my `JTable`. My `JTable` is using `DefaultTableModel`, here is the code I use for adding a new row:

```
AddDialog diag = new AddDialog(MainWindow.getInstance(),"Add Entity",true,tab);
diag.setVisible(true);
if(diag.isSaved()) {
    entity = diag.getEntity();
    table = diag.getTableModel();
    table.getEntities().add(entity);
    if(tab instanceof TablePreview) {
        tablePreview = (TablePreview)tab;
        tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) (tablePreview.getTableView().getModel());
        Object[] newRow = new Object[entity.getAttributes().size()];
        int i=0;
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : entity.getAttributes().entrySet()) { 
            newRow[i++]=entry;
        }
        tableModel.addRow(newRow);

    }else if(tab instanceof ChildTablePreview) {
        System.out.println("Tab is instanceof ChildTablePreview");
    }
}else {
    System.out.println("Entity not saved!");
}
```

diag is instance of `AddDialog` which extends `JDialog`, and when I fill in the fields of the dialog and click save it creates an `Entity` class which I want to add to the table as a new row. The logic works fine, but when the row gets inserted into the table, for some reason table looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJeuW.png]

If anyone has any idea how I can fix this, I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The problem is the data you add to the model. If you only want to see the value, then only add the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [custom cell renderer in your JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).

How data appears is based on the class of the columns.  The default renderer simply calls the .toString() function for the objects in the column. If the column contains a key value pair, its common for these to appear as key=value.

You need to set the renderer using the TableColumn method setCellRenderer.  You can define this renderer to only display the value for the objects in that column.